# Write to stdout and read from stdin in C

Tags: c, pipe

I am writing two c files that one is to write(by stdout) and another is read(by stdin).

But the read code is always hangs with read(), I have tried fread function but useless.

Can someone give advice?

Write example:

```
int main() {
    char *a_string="Hello";
    write(fileno(stdout), a_string, strlen(a_string)+1);

    return 0; 
}
```

Read example:

```
int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 100-1);
    printf("buffer=%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Comment: Normally your code will hang until you hit the Enter key. And furthermore  your string won't be zero terminated. Use rather `fgets` for reading, and `fputs` for writing.

Comment: Due to some reason, I want to use read() and write() only.

Comment: Hi @usr Its works, can I run these codes separately?

Comment: What is that _some reason_ you want to use `read` and `write`? What are you _actually_ trying to do ? Please read this : [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). And read this: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @黃思綸 You can't run them separately if you want them to communicate. If you don't want to use pipe then you'll have to use one of the [IPCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: I assume a POSIX or Linux operating system. Then read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ; perhaps you need a multiplexing call like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: I am studying two pipe codes that communicates to each other by read(stdin) and write(stdout). That's really amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The read code is always hangs with read(), I have tried fread function but useless.

This is because `read` and `fread`, unlike `fgets` and similar functions, do not quit reading when the user inputs a newline (presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>). It waits until EOF is read or until the specified bytes have been read.

To send EOF to `read` you must press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You need to input the [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) to stop, in Linux,it's Ctrl+D.

Comment: In linux, stdin and stdout are unnamed pipes. When you close all write descriptor for a pipe, it sends EOF to a read descriptor of this pipe.

Comment: @nopasara I don't see how this is particularly relevant.

Comment: @MD XF maybe not, i though he was piping two programs together. What for the first writing program exampled?

Comment: This is a signal you manually input, and when read() encounter this signal, it's return.